# Сделать прогрузку из файла через include

Tags: php

Сама прогрузка -

```
$verif = getVR(); include("{$verif}");
```

Код функции getVR -

```
function getVR() { 
    $veriff = "Pattern/verif"; 
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($veriff), true);
}
```

Что сделано не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: на будущее. все эти рюшечки с бантиками при обращении к переменной **не нужны.** и пишется просто `include $verif;`

Comment: а по сути - непонятно что требуется-то. getVR() должна возвращать имя файла?

Comment: Функция getVR должна выгружать содержимое в файле - в моем случае там точно местоположение нужного файла, которое должно быть в include

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в порядке вызова.

Надо **вначале подключить файл**, а только затем использовать метод. А не наоборот.

Также рекомендую усиленно ознакомиться с [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)